# Vertical spacing outside multline environment

Tags: multline

When using `multline` for parsing an equation, there's a larger vertical space above the equation than below. Why is this? It looks off. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{multline}
    {I_{xx,\,\mathrm{frus}}} = {I_{xx,\,\mathrm{hemi}}} - {I_{xx,\,\mathrm{cap}}} \\ - \left({V_{\mathrm{cap}}} m_{\mathrm{frus}} {V_{\mathrm{frus}}}^{-1}\right) {\left( {{{\bar z}_{\mathrm{cap}}} - {{\bar z}_{\mathrm{hemi}}}} \right)^2} - m_{\mathrm{frus}} {\left( {{{\bar z}_{\mathrm{frus}}} - {{\bar z}_{\mathrm{hemi}}}} \right)^2}
\end{multline}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the blank line before the `multline` environment. It causes the previous paragraph to end, and a bigger vertical space is the result.

For that matter, you may wish to remove the blank line after the environment too, unless the context really does call for a paragraph break (i.e., change of topic).

Comment: By the way, `\lipsum[2]` will end the paragraph nonetheless and the blank line actually does nothing. With normal text, however, the blank line should be removed as you say.

Comment: @egreg I thought it might too, but I experimented before I posted: On my system, `\lipsum[2]` does not end the paragraph, as verified by adding `zzz` directly after `\lipsum[2]`. (TeX Live 2018, updated in the past week; and `lipsum.sty` says `\ProvidesExplPackage{lipsum}{2019/01/02}{2.2}{150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text}`. Do you have a different version?

Comment: I forgot that the new version adds `\par` *at the beginning*